# JSON deserialize initialize all null objects

Tags: apex, json

Is there a way or any method (other than write a long helper for each object) that could initialize all objects within an object even if the JSON was not received aka:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public SomeObject objectHere;
```

I would want this to be automatically substantiated with an empty version of that object so when I go objectHere.id I don't have to null check the object then the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm) (`?.`) to avoid null checks:

```
String someValue = inputParam?.objectHere?.someProperty;
```

This is likely the best choice in many cases, unless you need to actually use the object for output, then you might want to go with [Derek's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/360317/2984).

Comment: wait what where have these been all my life!? I didn't know these were actually implemented I just heard ages ago that salesforce were thinking on adding them

Comment: @KarlLivesey You'd be forgiven for not knowing about them, they literally only came out just three releases ago. I actually helped fix a critical bug with it while it was in preview in Winter '21. It's helped me clean up a LOT of really ugly code. Also, you might have missed [this gem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/329745/2984) as well (greater-/less-than now return false with a null value instead of throwing NullPointerException).

Comment: my only other dream would be for lists it would end the for loop if null so like:


`for(Account Acc : AccList){
}`

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a way to initialize class variables without writing code to explicitly set those variables.

That's not just a JSON deserialization thing, though JSON deserialization makes things *just a bit more difficult* because it doesn't run any constructors for the type you're using.

You could turn your class variables into [properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) and take advantage of your ability to specify a getter to do lazy initialization.

Anonymous apex example:

```
public class LazyLoadVars{
    public Account myAcc {
        get{
            if(myAcc == null){ myAcc = new Account(); }
            return myAcc;
        }
        set;
    }
}

LazyLoadVars llv = new LazyLoadVars();
// Also works when deserializing from JSON
//LazyLoadVars llv = (LazyLoadVars)JSON.deserialize('{}', LazyLoadVars.class);

llv.myAcc.Name = 'Success!';

system.debug(llv);
```

I'm not sure if I would recommend such an approach, however. I get a dirty feeling when I read this that I can't quite put my finger on.

Comment: yeah this feels wrong =/

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing out of the box for this requirement. You'll need to roll your own initializer.