# Apex Trigger error ('Unexpected token ':' ')

Tags: apex, trigger

I've written this trigger, but there's an error that I can't resolve

The Trigger:

```apex
trigger AmounTtoWords on Receipt__c (before insert, before update) {
  for (Receipt__c **:** Trigger.new) {
        if (Total_Amount_Due__c != null && Total_Amount_Due__c >= 0) {
         
            Long n = c.Amount.longValue();
            string amo = ConvertCurrencyToWords.english_number(n);
            string amo1 = amo.remove(',');
            c.Amount_in_Words__c = amo1;
        } else {
            c.Amount_in_Words__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The Error:

[image]

Comment: You need to name the variable like `for (Receipt__c receipt : Trigger.new)` then use that to access the various field values like `receipt.Total_Amount_Due__c` etc. You also reference an undeclared variable `c` in some of this code.

Comment: In addition to @PhilW comment, you are referencing fields `Total_Amount_Due__c` without variable, so if you name your `Receipt__c`, for example, `Receipt__c receipt`, then you should reference to the field as `receipt.Total_Amount_Due__c`.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned in the comments already, you need to give a name to your variable. Also, you need to specify on which record you want to reference that field. So fixed code would look like:

```
for (Receipt__c c: Trigger.new) {
    if (c.Total_Amount_Due__c != null && c.Total_Amount_Due__c >= 0) {
        // Rest of your logic here
    }
}
```

Also, I guess that `c` should be your receipt, so I called it like that to minimize the changes you would need to do to your code. But please give your variables some meaningful names.
And think about using some sort of a [trigger framework](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/success-cloud-coding-conventions/implement-frameworks-sc), best practice is to have 1 line triggers that call your trigger framework and not having any logic inside your triggers.

Comment: FYI, comparison operators [no longer throw NullPointerException on null variables](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/329745/2984), so you can just write `if(c.Total_Amount_Due__c >= 0)`, which will return false on null.